# $\phi : \mathbb{Z}_5 \to $ H is a homomorphism, where H is a 5 order group .

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If $\phi(1) = a^3$, then $\phi(4)$ is ...?
How to get the answer correctly, I'm still beginner in abstract algebra.

Comment: This is very similar to your previous question. Did you understand the answers there? If so, you should accept one. Also, similar reasoning will help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a^5 = 1$, you have
$$\phi(4) = \phi(1+1+1+1) = \phi(1)\phi(1)\phi(1)\phi(1) = (\phi(1))^4 = a^{12} = a^5 a^5 a^2 = a^2.$$
You can't say much more than that: if for instance $H = \mathbb{Z}_5$, $a^2$ will have 5 different values depending on the 5 possible values of $a$.

Comment: Could you give me a clue why $a^5$ = 1, please?

Comment: @Yagami: This follows from [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29), applied to the subgroup of $H$ consisting of powers of $a$. In general, the order of an element divides the order of the group.

Comment: Then, if I've another question $\phi$ : Z5 --> H, where H = <a> is 5 order group, if $\phi(4)$ = a, what is $\phi(1)$?

I think, $\phi(4) = \phi(1+1+1+1) = \phi(1)\phi(1)\phi(1)\phi(1) = (\phi(1))^4 = $ a.

Then $\phi(1)$ is $a^[1/4]$?

Comment: @Yagami: Fractional powers are not necessarily very meaningful. In your case, you should realize that $\phi(1+4) = \phi(5)$ is trivial and use this to relate $\phi(1)$ to $\phi(4)$.